# Vagrant shell provisioner fails on Mac host but works on Windows host

Tags: windows, macos, shell, vagrant

I have the following vagrant file with a shell provisioner that works great on Windows 7 VirtualBox but fails when running on my macbook pro OSX 10.9.2

To be more specific, the provisioner "seems" to fail to install the requirements.txt. If I SSH into the box and re-run the bootstrap.sh as root it works. I understand the **long error** messages would be helpful, but I think the question is geared at understanding why a virtual box setup would work on one environment and not the other. Especially, when launching such a simple shell script.

Any thoughts or suggestions are much appreciated!

**Vagrant File**

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# Vagrantfile API/syntax version. Don't touch unless you know what you're doing!
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|

  config.vm.hostname = "test-box"

  config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise64"

  config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "bootstrap.sh"
end
```

**bootstrap.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

apt-get update
apt-get install -y build-essential curl git libffi-dev python-dev python-pip \
libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev python-software-properties g++ make

pip install --upgrade distribute
pip install -r /vagrant/requirements.txt
```

**requirements.txt**

```
Scrapy>=0.18.2
Twisted>=13.1.0
lxml>=3.2.3
queuelib>=1.0
w3lib>=1.3
```

Comment: I was able to run this without issue. Any updates? Can you post the error message your are seeing?

Comment: I looked at the VMs in both systems and realized the memory was very low in the MBP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The memory allocated to a VM is relative to the HOST's available memory. In this case, the MBP has 4gb and the VM was defaulted to about 300mb. This was not enough to successfully install the requirements.txt. A fix would be to increase the min memory needed in the Vagrant file, for example:

> config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
>
> ```
> vb.memory = 2048
> vb.cpus = 2
> ```
>
> end

The lesson in this is to make sure to set the Vagrant file with as much detail as possible to accurately replicate across systems.